# Python Module Import from another directory

Tags: python-2.7

I'm getting a module import error.

My main file is `/home/mininet/pythonscripts/import.py`:
[image: Main file program]

and my module file is `/home/mininet/test/hello.py`:
[image: module file program]

The error I'm getting is:

```
File "import.py", line 7, in <module> from test.hello import sqr,print_func 
ImportError: No module named hello
```

i also added the `__init__.py` file in the module search path..please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to import `/home/mininet/test/hello.py` as `test.hello`, you have to fulfill two requirements:

1. `/home/mininet/test/__init__.py` must exist to mark `test` as a package.
2. `/home/mininet` must be on `sys.path` so that Python finds `test/hello.py` when looking for `test.hello`.

Note that having `/home/mininet/test` on `sys.path` lets you `import hello`, but not `import test.hello`.

Comment: Thanks it works.But do we have to do it everytime i.e. add sys.path.insert() code in all our module dependent codes(if the module resides in another directory)..it's quite cumbersome.any other option

Comment: The script's path is always on `sys.path`, as is the standard library. So, one option is to have your script in the same directory as the package (e.g. in `/home/mininet`, or move `test` to `/home/mininet/pythonscripts`). Alternatively, you can use [`.pth` files](http://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html) to add certain directories to `sys.path` automatically on startup.